# Form always redirecting to the same page when submit Contact Form 7

Tags: wordpress, forms, redirect, contact-form-7, ajaxform

I have use this plugin in all the web sites I worked. I used it for my current site as well (latest version – 4.6.1) with latest wordpress 4.7.2. But I am getting following error.

Instead of Ajax submission it is redirecting the page and this hash “`#wpcf7-f195-p4-o1`” appending to the URL. If I fill correctly and submit, mail is sending fine except this hash appending and page redirecting issue.

Why it is redirecting and appending the hash (form ID/action) to the current URL.

Assume I am submitting my contact us form. Then the resulting URL is `contact-us/#wpcf7-f195-p4-o1`

Thanks

Comment: That's normally due to a JS issue. What's the URL?

Comment: @KerynGill Thanks for asking. I already fixed it.

Comment: Might be helpful to answer your own question in case someone finds this and is having the same issue :)